# How do I make my ip public facing?

Tags: ip

I tried Ngrok and that works, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to expose the local ports to public addresses. Any pointers or references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup port forwarding.

How to do this varies between different routing devices but [here](http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8790/~/how-do-i-set-up-port-forwarding-on-my-bt-hub%3F) is an example for BT Homehubs.

You've not provided much information but say, for a webserver, here's what you want to do:

- set your local IP address to a static one (192.168.1.15 for example). You can always run `ifconfig` or `ip address` to see what your current dynamic one is and set that as your static.
- On your router setup port forwarding from port 80 / 443 / whatever to the listening webserver port on your local server.
- set the DNS records to point to your router's IP address.

That's it. It's a PITA on home networks though, which it sounds likely that you're using, as they generally do not have static IP addresses assigned to them. This is something that you would have to discuss with your ISP.

Comment: Ok, port forwarding on routers... Say I was using Starbucks wifi and wanted to do something like that? Ngrok seems like the only solution I found so far.

Comment: Yeah that would be the most reliable solution I can think of.

Comment: I found a good discussion on ycombinator: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7585056

Comment: That's a pretty interesting tool, never heard of it before. However, it looks pretty much the same as ngrok. Depending on the setup, and what you're trying to achieve, SSH tunneling *may* be an option but if Starbucks were to notice what you were up to I'm not too sure how pleased they'd be...

Comment: well, I'm sure Starbucks doesn't care enough to be pleased or not. ssh -f -N -q -L 1143:localhost:143 username@imap.example.com , works but I need an SSH server running on my host server... and heroku doesn't have ssh. I'm a cheapskate and I only pay for things I use. If there's a host that has SSH and decent storage under $8 a month, I may consider cancelling my gym membership for a server. Any ideas?